# preg_replace, character escapes & accented characters. /u works on one server, but not another

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, pcre

I have the following code:

```
 preg_replace('/[^\w-]/u','.','Bréánná MÓÚLÍN');
```

Which on server A (PHP 5.3.5) returns:
"Bréánná.Móúlín" (as it should)

However, on server B (PHP 5.2.11) it returns:
"Br..n..M..l.n" (not what what I want at all)

Am I right in thinking that this is down to whether or not PCRE_UCP was set when the whole thing was compiled?

Is there any way of overriding this if this is the case?

Failing that, is there any way of easily replacing such characters with a 'standard' equivalent? (Like utf8_decode but more expansive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether `PCRE_UCP` defined during compilation affects `preg_replace()`, but a work-around to your problem is to use the multibyte string function [`mb_ereg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php):

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");

echo mb_ereg_replace('[^0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-˿Ͱ-ͽͿ-῿‌-‍⁰-↏Ⰰ-⿯、-퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-�̀-ͯ‿-⁀\\-]','.','Bréánná MÓÚLÍN');
```

PHP 5.2 results: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UnZeyf

**EDIT:** I originally thought that the multibyte ereg functions supported [Unicode character type escapes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), but this turns out not to be true. Instead, you need to determine the ranges of characters that you consider "letters". I used the character ranges from the [XML Standard's definition of `NameChar`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameChar) with the following Java program to generate the RegExp string (as apparently the multibyte ereg functions do not support Unicode character escape sequences, either):

```
import java.io.*;

public class SO7456963 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("SO7456963.txt"), "UTF-8");
        w.write("[^0-9A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02FF\u0370-\u037D\u037F-\u1FFF\u200C-\u200D\u2070-\u218F\u2C00-\u2FEF\u3001-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFFD\u0300-\u036F\u203F-\u2040\\\\-]");
        w.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm trying to replace non-word characters (non-hyphen too) with a . however, which that code doesn't accomplish. What are the \\pL and \\pN? I'm not familiar with them so I don't know how to change it to do what I want.

Comment: @Toukakoukan: They specify sets of characters by Unicode property. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: @Toukakoukan: I found out that the multibyte ereg functions do not support the special `\p{...}` PCRE syntax for specifying characters by Unicode property. See my updated answer.